# How do I get the text inside every filled cell of the B column in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I started off with something along the lines of

```
function yes () { 
var sheet  =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();


  sheet.appendRow([c1]);
  var Dash  = sheet.getLastRow();





  var d1 = sheet.getRange(Dash, 2)


sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow([d1]);

}
```

I don't know if this one actually works since I've fiddled with these lines for so long that I don't remember the exact configuration but here are the results I got with different configurations of these lines, all of them having a comma implemented between each of them unlike what is in the model since I forgot the exact code I used and frankly i'm too burnt out from trialing and erroring this projected.

If I had 1, 2, 3, 4 in the B column, here's what I could get

undefined, 1, 2, 3, 4

or

1,

or

2,

or

3,

or

4,

or

undefined,

Answer (score 1):

```
function allTheTextInColumnB() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  vA.map(function(r){if(r[0])return r[0];});
  Logger.log(vA.join(''));
}
```